# remove dupe bookmarks in firefox?

Tags: firefox

I dont need something preventing me from favouriting something i already have (which was the only solution i found many months ago). In my bookmark list i have multiple bookmarks of the exact same url. I am not sure how it happened. Also i know i will be loading bookmarks from json so there should be dupes coming from that.

How do i filter out all the dupes? and its literally the exact same url, not `http://superuser.com/questions/ask` vs `http://**www.**superuser.com/questions/ask`

Answer (score 2):

Try [Bookmark Duplicate Detector](http://bookmarkdd.mozdev.org/) addon ([installation](http://bookmarkdd.mozdev.org/installation.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I use a Firefox add-on called '[CheckPlaces](http://www.andyhalford.com/checkplaces/)' - I've used it for quite a while and it has yet to let me down :)
It can do other things too like checking that your bookmarks actually still exist by way of timeouts and 404's etc. (I always go through the list of bookmarks it outputs just in case)

Answer (score 0):

I setup a filter using SED, uniq, and sort (in that order) to filter out a lot of the dupes. Once I've run sort, all the URLs that are close enough dupes, e.g. superuser.com, superuser/user are easy to spot.

You should be able to import the bookmarks back into firefox after. I did that when I had way too many bookmarks that I never sorted through.

Comment: So i take it i need to export the list in HTML instead of json and import it again? Actually i am looking and it seems a little complex. I'm unsure how to sed uniq that and make it able to import again. Now that i am looking at the json output it doesn't look too difficult to write a custom app.